# JSRender with typescript

Tags: typescript, jsrender

Is there any JSRender typescript implementation out there?

I want to call .render() method from a typescript file but don't have a typescript implementation of JSRender.js

Any ideas guys?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There probably isn't yet, but you can start by adding your own `jsrender.d.ts` file to your program for the parts you need. As it is a jQuery plugin, you will need to add to the JQuery interface.

```
/// <reference path="./jquery.d.ts" />

interface JQuery {
    render(data: any);
}

$("body").render("");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a fast solution to just work (or test)

```
var testWrapper :any = $;
testWrapper.render("");
```